# Using python-asyncio, how can I read the urls instead of listing the urls inside the main function?

Tags: python, csv, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have a list of urls saved inside a text file called file.txt. How can I have this script read from the txt file and save the response to a text file instead of listing the urls inside the function? There are too many urls to list so the function will get complicated to look at. Thank you

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from codetiming import Timer

async def task(name, work_queue):
    timer = Timer(text=f"Task {name} elapsed time: {{:.1f}}")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while not work_queue.empty():
            url = await work_queue.get()
            print(f"Task {name} getting URL: {url}")
            timer.start()
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                await response.text()
            timer.stop()

async def main():
    """
    This is the main entry point for the program
    """
    # Create the queue of work
    work_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # Put some work in the queue
    for url in [
        "http://google.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://linkedin.com",
        "http://apple.com",
        "http://microsoft.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://twitter.com",
    ]:
        await work_queue.put(url)

    # Run the tasks
    with Timer(text="\nTotal elapsed time: {:.1f}"):
        await asyncio.gather(
            asyncio.create_task(task("One", work_queue)),
            asyncio.create_task(task("Two", work_queue)),
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Text.file contents

```
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
http://linkedin.com
http://apple.com
http://microsoft.com
http://facebook.com
```

Comment: What is the separator in the .txt file? Newlines, commas, spaces? Better yet, could you post a sample of how the file looks? Welcome to StackOverflow btw.

Comment: @SebastianLiendo I have edited to include the file. The separator in the txt.file are newlines. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't need to load the urls asynchronously. You can load the urls before running the `main` function. Define the `main` function so it accepts the parameter `urls` and finally loop through the urls.

```py
async def main(urls):
  queue = asyncio.Queue()
  for url in urls:
    await queue.put(url)
  
  # rest of your code


if __name__ == "__main__":
  with open("urls.txt") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    urls = data.split("\n")[:-1]
  asyncio.run(main(urls))
```

Comment: How would this fit into the script posted originally? I do not understand.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't being really descriptive, sorry. I edited the response so it is more clear (I hope).

Comment: Hello, I have been working on this but still cannot get it to run. Can you explain more please? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, since loading the urls from the text file is neither IO bound or cpu bound, you just can load them before starting all asynchronous operations. So before running the `main` function, load the urls and pass them as an argument to the function. You can then schedule and run all your tasks.